# Using jQuery.Deferred over variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, deferred

*When ajax complete I can use  done,error,always deferred methods . 
But I can do this because  `jqXHR` object,  is derived from a Deferred object.*

But How can I mimic this behavior over this simple example :

I have a variable named `t`.

I want the done function to be called when `t` get's its value.

Something like this : (*psuedo*)

```
var t;
setTimeout(function (){t=100;},3000);
t.done(function (){alert('');}); //im expecting this alert after 3 seconds.
```

How can I do this ?

*p.s. I know i can call the alert in the callback function(obviously). but again. I want to apply the deferred behaviour*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use just a variable which you assign to. Instead, create a [`jQuery.Deferred` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) manually, and [`.resolve()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) it:

```
var t = new $.Deferred();
setTimeout(function() {
    t.resolve(100);
}, 3000);
t.done(function(val) {
    alert(val);
}); // this will alert "100" after 3 seconds
```

Comment: Just FYI the `new` keyword before `$.Deferred()` is optional.

Comment: @jerome.s: I know, but I like its emphasizing of the constructor behaviour (even though [it's a factory](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js) actually)